# Is -in' really correct?

Tags: suffixes

I wanted to know if -in' is really correct. Because I couldn't found a single article about the -in' ending.

Examples:

**-ing**
Runn**ing**
Jump**ing**

**-in'**
Runn**in'**
Jump**in'**

Comment: In direct speech, it's simply a representation of the way some speakers drop the 'g' when pronouncing '-ing' words. This is a feature of many kinds of colloquial speech and also, apparently, used to occur in British upper-class speech (Dorothy Sayers' detective Lord Peter Wimsey speaks like that).

Comment: When I was at school aged 6, there was a poster in our classrom about 'poor g' which showed a letter g with a little face looking really sad because kids went runnin', swimmin', playin', etc, (you could see them having fun in the background)  and left the 'g' behind. The idea was to make us speak 'properly' and not like little Cockneys.

Comment: The apostrophe at the end indicates that a letter has been omitted. In this case, it is the "g". As others have pointed out, this is used in dialog.

Comment: Note that it's not actually dropping a G, it's using a different final consonant /n/ instead of /ŋ/ in some words. http://jon-west-language.blogspot.com/2013/03/are-you-listenin-phenomenon-of-g.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#G-dropping

Comment: This is an example of [eye dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect), that is, deliberately changing the "proper" spelling of a word to match the way it is spoken by a particular person or group of people.